# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded ajax google maps

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps

Can someone help

I'm doing a google maps project drawing shapes(circles, polygons, rectangles ...etc) and saving it to the database to reload it later 
in order to save for example a circle I'm doing this:

```
if (event.type === 'circle') {

  CIRCLES.push({
    "centerLat": event.overlay.center.lat(),
    "centerLng": event.overlay.center.lng(),
    "radius": event.overlay.radius,
    "fillColor": event.overlay.fillColor,
    "fillOpacity": event.overlay.fillOpacity,
    "strokeWeight": event.overlay.strokeWeight,
    "zIndex": event.overlay.zIndex
  });

  var cirlceArea = Math.PI * Math.pow(event.overlay.radius, 2);
  var circleInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content:'<h5>Circle Area</h5><b>'+cirlceArea +'M²</b>',
    position:event.overlay.center,
    map:map
  });
  // circleInfoWindow.setMap(map);
  // circleInfoWindow.open(map);

  infoWindowArr.push(circleInfoWindow);
```

the code till now is working fine but when I submit the data using jquery ajax it triggers this error Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
but when i comment this line of code  `infoWindowArr.push(circleInfoWindow);`
it work fine 
and finally, this is my ajax

```
$("#map-form").on("submit", function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  url: '/dash/store',
  data: {
    "circles": CIRCLES,
    "polygons": POLYGONS,
    "rectangles":RECTANGLES,
    "polylines":POLYLINES,
    "projectName":projectName,
    "description":description,
    "infoWindow":infoWindowArr, 
    /*'captcha':grecaptcha.getResponse()*/
  }
```

I looked into many similar questions here but didn't find a solution
and I think it' coming from the ajax request 
and thank you

Comment: Why you need multiple infoWindow instances? You can just add different content to the same instance.

Comment: an infowindow for each circle to hold The calculated area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that jQuery is calling JSON.stringify on the "data" object in the request parameters and there is a cycle in the graph (it goes into endless recursion). So instead of pushing the circleInfoWindow object(which has references to the map amongst other things), simply push the relevant parameters like:

```
infoWindowArr.push({
   content:'<h5>Circle Area</h5><b>'+cirlceArea +'M²</b>',
   position:event.overlay.center,
});
```

Comment: i'm pushing the hole infowindow object because i need to  undo the last shape drown and it's  infowindow

Comment: Okay, so you are storing some data on the server to do "undo" operations? You can't just send an infoWindow object to the server (it contains a lot of other objects that you do not need like a reference to the map and DOM elements) and it goes into endless recursion. Send an id for the object and if you need to undo, simply find the object again on the client-side via the id and then remove it.

Comment: but I don't know how to find an infoWindow by its id I'll appreciate it and thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I think I've solved this by emptying the array that holds all shapes before submitting the ajax request thank you  @eerik-kivistik for your help and your time

Comment: You are welcome! 
Also, if the answer was helpful, accept it as the answer, if not, let's leave it at that.